# Can C++ pass empty pointer to a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, reference

For example, I want to declare pointer to array and to don't wanna initialize it. Then, I want pass it to a function and initialize it exactly in function. How can I do it in C++?

```
void F(int *B, const int& N) {
    B = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) B[i] = i;
}

int main() {

    int N = 4;
    int *B = nullptr; // doesn't work

    F(*B, N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        cout << B[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It evokes/produces error corresponds to the problem that B has no reference to point and, therefore he can't initialize array.

error: Process finished with exit code 11

Comment: please include the error message in the question

Comment: `B` is a `int*` but `*B` is an `int`

Comment: offtopic: do not use operators `new` and `delete` explicitly! This was acceptable before C++11. Use `std::vector` `std::unique_ptr` `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 done. Idk, but sometimes it just shows me only code error and nothing else.

Comment: @MarekR yeah, true in some real projects, but I wanna understand it

Comment: @kot_mapku3 There is no significant difference, just responsibility for adding respective `delete` is moved to standard library and compiler, so it is harder to make an faulty code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pointer you pass is a copy of the original pointer. When you modify `B` in `F`, `B` i `main()` remains the same.

You need to pass the pointer by reference or pass a pointer to the pointer:

```
void F(int*& B, const int& N) {
    B = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) B[i] = i;
}

int main() {

    int N = 4;
    int *B = nullptr; // doesn't work

    F(B, N); //no operator here, just pass the pointer by reference

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        cout << B[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

or

```
void F(int** B, const int& N) {
    *B = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) (*B)[i] = i;
}

int main() {

    int N = 4;
    int *B = nullptr; // doesn't work

    F(&B, N); //need address-of operator

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        cout << B[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Also, since you decided to use manual memory management, you are also responsible to release the memory acquired with `new`. This is not necessary if you use `std::vector` as your container instead of raw pointer (or `std::unique_ptr` or other containers).

```
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        cout << B[i] << endl;

    delete[] B; //release memory after use
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have at least two problems.

The first in in the call where you use `*B`. `*B` is the same as `B[0]`, which means you're attempting to pass a single `int` element to the function. But since `B` is a null pointer, the dereference will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Correct (to fit the shown function signature) would be plain `B`:

```
F(B, N);
```

---

The second problem is that passing arguments to functions by default is done *by value*. Which means that the value of `B` is copied into the local variable `B` inside the function `F`.

When you assign to `B` in the function you only change the local copy, and the original value in the `main` function will be unmodified.

To solve this you need to pass `B` by *reference*:

```
void F(int*& B, const int N) { ... }
```